# Export excel table as xml using xml mappings and Open XML

Tags: c#, xml, excel, openxml

I'm looking for a way to export Excel table content using xml mappings in C# using Open XML SDK. So far the closest thing I found was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309174/programmatically-export-excel-files-to-xml-using-xmlmaps) which is using Office Interop which we're trying to avoid.
I found CustomXMLMappingsPart and MapInfo classes to be related to this, but couldn't find anything that would allow to perform the export process itself.

Is this even possible with Open XML SDK?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no easy way to accomplish this. The only way I found was to read the table content yourself and then use TableColumn.XmlColumnDefinitions.XPath to construct the xml.